# Apache Camel DynamicRouter - still route after returning null from bean method

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have defined the route with dynamic router bean in Spring XML as follows

```
<route id="dynamic-recipientList-route" >
        <from uri="direct-vm:b2bfwk-post" />
                <log message="dynamic-recipientList-route received=${body}" />
                <dynamicRouter>
                    <method ref="dynamicRouter" method="route" />
                </dynamicRouter>
    </route>
```

The dynamicRouter bean java code is implemented as below:

```
public String route(Exchange inExch) {

    LOG.info("Enter DynamicRouterBean ... " + inExch.getIn().getBody());
    return whereToGo(inExch);
}

/**
 * Method which computes where to go next
 */
private String whereToGo(Exchange inExch) {

    int invoked = 0;
    Object current = inExch.getProperty("invoked");

    if(current != null){
        invoked = Integer.valueOf(current.toString());
        LOG.info("In progress of dynamic route... invoked = " + invoked + " ... " + inExch.getIn().getBody());
    }
    else{
        //Message enter dynamic router for the first time... invoked = 0
        LOG.info("Message enter dynamic router for the first time... invoked = 0 ... " + inExch.getIn().getBody());
    }
    invoked++;
    inExch.setProperty("invoked", invoked);

    if (invoked == 1) {
        // 1st time
        LOG.info("route to step 1 ... " + inExch.getIn().getBody());
        return "direct-vm://step1";

    } else if (invoked == 2) {
        // 2nd time 
        LOG.info("route to step 2 ... " + inExch.getIn().getBody());
        return "direct-vm://step2";

    } else {
        // no more, so return null to indicate end of dynamic router
        LOG.info("All Steps finished for message " + inExch.getIn().getBody());
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the "steps" routes configured as below

```
<route id="app-route-step1" >
        <from uri="direct-vm:step1" />
            <log message="step1 received=${headers}, ${body}" />
            <delay><constant>1000</constant></delay>
            <to uri="direct-vm:b2bfwk-post" />
    </route>

    <route id="app-route-step2" >       
        <from uri="direct-vm:step2" />
            <log message="step2 received=${headers}, ${body}" />
            <delay><constant>1000</constant></delay>
            <to uri="direct-vm:b2bfwk-post" />
    </route>
```

The bean will add a property "invoked" into the Exchange, in which the value will increment by 1 per each call to DynamicRouter bean. When it reach 3, router bean will return null and the Exchange should stop routing.

However, I found from the log that after null is returned, the Exchange object still route into the Dynamic Router bean once more, with "invoked=4"... again it will return null, and the routing of this Exchange object stopped. I suppose that the routing of Exchange object should stop by "invoked=3" as the Dynamic Router returns null. It seems that one extra routing was happened unexpectedly... Any possible mis-config or potential issue in my router bean code?

Below supplement the log... notice that the "All Steps finished..." statement appeared twice...

```
2015-08-26 12:46:42,418 INFO  multiconsumer-route            - multiconsumer-route received, header={breadcrumbId=ID--53870-1440564388141-0-1, CamelFileAbsolute=false, CamelFileAbsolutePath=D:\EclipseLunaSR2\eclipse_workspace\camelInAction\dynamic-route\target\inbox\smallfile.csv, CamelFileContentType=application/vnd.ms-excel, CamelFileLastModified=1440560415206, CamelFileLength=16, CamelFileName=smallfile.csv, CamelFileNameConsumed=smallfile.csv, CamelFileNameOnly=smallfile.csv, CamelFileParent=target\inbox, CamelFilePath=target\inbox\smallfile.csv, CamelFileRelativePath=smallfile.csv, JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=Queue[camelInAction.sample.inventory], JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:EMS-SERVER.20B455DAC6251A7:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=null, JMSTimestamp=1440564402407, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=null, testHeader=headerValue}
2015-08-26 12:46:42,419 INFO  dynamic-recipientList-route    - dynamic-recipientList-route received=123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,422 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - Enter DynamicRouterBean ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,422 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - Message enter dynamic router for the first time... invoked = 0 ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,422 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - route to step 1 ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,433 INFO  app-route-step1                - step1 received=123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,433 INFO  dynamic-recipientList-route    - dynamic-recipientList-route received=123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,434 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - Enter DynamicRouterBean ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,434 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - In progress of dynamic route... invoked = 1 ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,434 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - route to step 2 ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,434 INFO  app-route-step2                - step2 received=123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,435 INFO  dynamic-recipientList-route    - dynamic-recipientList-route received=123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,435 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - Enter DynamicRouterBean ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,435 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - In progress of dynamic route... invoked = 2 ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,435 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - All Steps finished for message 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,437 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - Enter DynamicRouterBean ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,437 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - In progress of dynamic route... invoked = 3 ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,437 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - All Steps finished for message 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,438 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - Enter DynamicRouterBean ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,438 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - In progress of dynamic route... invoked = 4 ... 123,0,bumper,4
2015-08-26 12:46:42,438 INFO  DynamicRouterBean              - All Steps finished for message 123,0,bumper,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your code does before getting to that route but i get the following working with that code:

```
@Test
public void testName() throws Exception {
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:a").dynamicRouter().method(new WhereToGo());
            from("direct-vm://step1").log("Step1: ${body}");
            from("direct-vm://step2").log("Step2: ${body}");
        }
    });

    template.sendBody("direct:a", "data");
    Thread.sleep(6000);
}
```

Giving the following:

```
13:42:56.000 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - Enter DynamicRouterBean ... data
13:42:56.000 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - Message enter dynamic router for the first time... invoked = 0 ... data
13:42:56.001 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - route to step 1 ... data
13:42:56.009 [main] INFO  route2 - Step1: data
13:42:56.012 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - Enter DynamicRouterBean ... data
13:42:56.012 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - In progress of dynamic route... invoked = 1 ... data
13:42:56.012 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - route to step 2 ... data
13:42:56.013 [main] INFO  route3 - Step2: data
13:42:56.014 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - Enter DynamicRouterBean ... data
13:42:56.014 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - In progress of dynamic route... invoked = 2 ... data
13:42:56.014 [main] INFO  n.n.WhereToGoTest - All Steps finished for message data
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your code sample. Finally I recognized what wrong. In the "steps" routes I have added a "to" back to the DynamicRouter route, but it should be no needed. The issue is not found after I removed those "to"